# Start a new activity from an Imagebutton inside a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-imagebutton

I have my `Fragment` class with a `Button` and I want to start a new `activity` with this `button`.
Could someone help me please?

Here is my **MainFragment.class**:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    public MainFragment() {

        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: first override on activity created and find your view there. Then it is just starting the intent from your fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  view.findViewById(R.id.buttonId).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(...));
        }
    });
}
```

Replace `buttonId` with the id of the button and fill out the `intent`.